# reactjs call a function

Tags: reactjs, function

I have a class API with a function which I wish to call in my component.

```
export default function(authentification){
axios.post('/login',params)
.then(response=> {
  localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.headers.authorization);
  localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED, true);
  this.setState({isAuthenticated:true});
})
.catch(error =>{
  const statusCode = error.response.status;
  if(statusCode === 401)
    errors.authentification = true;
  else if (statusCode === 404)
    errors.resource = true;
  else
    errors.server = true;

    this.setState({errors});
});
}
```

I do not arrive in found how to call this function in my component and as to get back its result to put it in setState

Comment: You wouldn't call `this.setState()` from your exported function. You should create a function that does the authentication, and then returns a Promise if the authentication was successful or failed. In your `componentDidMount()`, or `onSubmit()`, call the function and in the component itself, use `this.setState()` to update the state variables.

Answer (score 0):

First: separate your setState from your api helper method like:

```
export default function(authentification){
  axios.post('/login',params)
  .then(response=> {
    localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.headers.authorization);
    localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED, true);
    return {status: "ok"}
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    const statusCode = error.response.status;
    if(statusCode === 401)
      errors.authentification = true;
    else if (statusCode === 404)
      errors.resource = true;
    else
      errors.server = true;
    return {status: "error", errors}
  });
}
```

Or if you want to use a async/await syntax in your api method:

```
const authentification = async (params) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/login',params);
    const statusCode = response.status;
    if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
        localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.headers.authorization);
        localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED, true);
        return {status: "ok"}
    }
    let errors = {};
    if (statusCode === 401) {
        errors.authentification = true;
    }
    else if (statusCode === 404) {
        errors.resource = true;
    }
    else {
        errors.server = true;
    }
    return {status: "error", errors}
}

export default authentification;
```

Then call you api function inside of `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method of your Component like:

```
...
componentDidMount = async () => {
  let resp = await helperfunction();
  if (resp.status === "ok") {
    this.setState({isAuthenticated:true});
    return;
  }
  this.setState({resp.errors});
}
...
```

Comment: Which is the best solution: the first one or the second

Comment: You can choose what you would like to use ... async/await is just a newer syntax of javacsript. I'll made a change to my answer to rewrite your api function into async await too so you will have it consistent

Answer (score 0):

in a file.js create all function you want and export it

```
let xxx = (authentification) => {
axios.post('/login',params)
.then(response=> {
  localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.headers.authorization);
  localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED, true);
  this.setState({isAuthenticated:true});
})
.catch(error =>{
  const statusCode = error.response.status;
  if(statusCode === 401)
    errors.authentification = true;
  else if (statusCode === 404)
    errors.resource = true;
  else
    errors.server = true;

    this.setState({errors});
});
}

export default xxx;
```

then import it where you wanna use it like so --> import xxx from 'path';

Answer (score 0):

I restructured my code. I do not know if it is the good architecture to employee. But I does not obtain answer in my component yet

Classe AuthentificationAPI :

```
import axios from "axios";

const AuthentificationAPI = {
login(params){
    return  axios.post('/login',params);
},
}

export {AuthentificationAPI as default}
```

AuthentificationService :

```
import { ACCESS_TOKEN, IS_AUTHENTICATED } from "constants/constants.js";
import AuthentificationAPI from "api//authentificationAPI.js";

const AuthentificationService = {
login(params){
    let errors  = {};

    AuthentificationAPI.login(params).then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.headers.authorization);
        localStorage.setItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED, true);

        return {isAuthenticated:true};
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const statusCode = error.response.status;

        if(statusCode === 401)
            errors.authentification = true;
        else if (statusCode === 404)
            errors.resource = true;
        else
            errors.server = true;

        return errors;
      });

    },
 }

 export {AuthentificationService as default}
```

Call in my component :

> ```
>   let resp = AuthentificationService.login(params);
>
>   console.log(resp);
> ```